# Implementing ViewPager with Swipe and Button

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've been looking around for a way to slide my tabs left/right inside my tabhost (*must be Android 2.1 compatible, so no FragmentManagers, etc*) to display separate layouts. There are many examples using ViewPager so I ditched the Tabhost and opted to implement this [code](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/). I've got some test code below which uses two "screens". I will need to be able to progmatically switch between screens when the user enters a query (here screen1), and then to display a page of results (screen2). The user may also swipe back-and-forth between the query page and results page.

The problem I'm having is how to implement the onClickListener for the button. Normally, I would implement this in screen1.java (below) but onClickListener never seems to get control when I click the button.  I guess the way ViewPager works the screen1 layout is somehow bundled up in the ViewPager object.  I tried inflating the view to get at the button in screen1, but things got messy and it wasn't straightforward.

What I've got working is a static member variable of my ViewPager (myPager) in FlingActivity. From the PagerAdapter, when screen1 is instantiated, I can set the onClickListener to the button object,when the view is inflated, and then reference the static variable FlingActivity.myPager to setCurrentItem() when the button is clicked (changing the view).

Thing is, this all seems really kludgy. What would I need to do to get my onClickListener back in my screen1.java class?

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

screen1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab1_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

screen2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab2_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

screen1.java

```
package test.com.vfling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class screen1 extends Activity
{
    private final String TAG = "** screen1 **";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        Log.d (TAG, "oncreate");
        setContentView (R.layout.screen1);
    }

}
```

screen2.java

```
package test.com.vfling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class screen2 extends Activity 
{
    private final String TAG = "** screen2 **";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        Log.d (TAG, "oncreate");
        setContentView (R.layout.screen2);      
    }


}
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
package test.com.vfling;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private String TAG = "** MyPagerAdapter **";

    @Override
    public int getCount ()
    {
        //Log.d (TAG, "getCount");
        return 2;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem (View collection, int position)
    {
        Log.d (TAG, "instantiateItem");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext ().getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                                resId = R.layout.screen1;
                                Log.d (TAG, "screen1");
            break;
            case 1:
                                resId = R.layout.screen2;                               
                                Log.d (TAG, "screen2");
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate (resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView (view, 0);


        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                                Button b = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.button1);
                                b.setOnClickListener (ocl);
                                Log.d (TAG, "screen1");
            break;
        }


        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem (View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2)
    {
        Log.d (TAG, "destroyitem");
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView ((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject (View arg0, Object arg1)
    {
        Log.d (TAG, "isviewfromobject");
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState ()
    {
        return null;
    }


    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId ())
            {
                        case R.id.button1:
                    Log.d (TAG, "button 1 click");
                        FlingActivity.myPager.setCurrentItem (1);
                        break;
            }

        }
    };
}
```

FlingActivity.java

```
package test.com.vfling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FlingActivity extends Activity
{
    private final String TAG = "** test_vfling **";
    public static ViewPager myPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
       setContentView (R.layout.main);

       MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter ();
       myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.myfivepanelpager);
       myPager.setAdapter (adapter);
       myPager.setCurrentItem (1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter, but you don't add views or fragments to the adapter. Have a look at the documentation, it shows how to do this properly. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm coding for 2.1

Comment: It's not about the version of android, it's about the proper use of ViewPager.